# How to run same build of react / webpack app on different environments

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, staging

I am building a single page application using *React* and *Webpack*. For the testing purposes, I need to be able to build application and then run the same build on both *staging* and *production* environment with different setup (*staging* setup should use staging APIs, where *production* should use production ones)

I am aware of approaches using *envify*, *DefinePlugin*, *dotEnv* however, all of them do require the environment variable values to be known at the build time.

I am looking for something really similar to *dotEnv* where I will have just one file, which I can hot switch on production for one with production values, and without the need of change in application

Any ideas how to achieve that? Once obvious solution would be to define publicly accessible env.js file, which would define sort of global object, but that does not seem to be elegant enough :(

Comment: Really, no solution yet after 3 years :)) ?!

Comment: @errogaht - the reason might be that there is no obvious answer :). Since then I have used various different methods. From simple ones where I did have different env.json files and only specific one got deployed and the dynamically loaded by the application. To the really complex ones, where there was a separate Discovery service deployed on same domain providing me with the other environment variables